# can I start simple, small, single mongodb instance, and switch to replicaset later easily, or shall I make it "replicable" from day one?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I need to get things done, quick and fast and now.

Later on, down the road, say in a month or less, or more, I will want to have my database replicated in few more machines.

I wonder, if I can simply start working on my single instance, and start worrying about replication later on, or there are things I need to take into account now to make it easier to replicate later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mostly can worry about it later on. If you switch to replica sets you will have to restart your mongod process and set up a replica set at that time though. If you want to avoid that you can also consider simply running a 3 member replication set on a single machine to save yourself any headaches later on.

This should give you a good overview of the pros/cons : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Upgrading+to+Replica+Sets

Comment: thanks. mongo is a great tool to start-with, and this is just one more reason why.

Comment: It definitely is. Good luck ;)

Comment: You can run a one-node replica set, and it will work (almost exactly) like a standalone server (it will have an oplog, but otherwise effectively equivalent). This prevents you from needing to restart the `mongod` process if/when you decide to add more nodes to your replica set.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Remon's answer, you can even convert your system from a single node (or a single replica set) to a cluster, without even restarting your mongod instances (you'll have to restart your app, though).

Comment: Fair point ;) But that does require that mongod to have been started with --replSet <name> though correct?

Comment: No, you can make a cluster out of individual mongod's

Comment: Hm, how would that work? Mongod processes started without the --replSet option are not repset aware.

Comment: It seems that you're mixing replication and sharding. These concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: Am I? I don't think so. Both are cluster solutions conceptually and both replica sets and sharding require the mongod daemons to be (re)started with the appropriate command line parameters (--replSet and --shardsvr respectively). Omitting these will/may cause incorrect housekeeping of the cluster related data in these operating modes. Are you saying starting a single node or a repset without the --shardsvr flag will still make them functional shards?

Comment: @RemonvanVliet: yep, `--shardsvr` only changes the port, nothing else.
And let's get terminology clear: cluster consists of shards. Shard can be a mongod or replica set. :-)

Comment: didn't know about the --shardsvr only affecting the port, thanks!. Cluster is defined as a group of individual servers that are conceptually grouped so both rep sets and a sharding cluster would qualify. A cluster consists of multiple servers. For example a full sharded setup with multiple mongod processes on a single machine doesn't qualify as a cluster (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(computing)) but details ;) Thanks for the info on the port thing!

Comment: "Cluster" in MongoDB parlance typically refers to a sharded cluster, where nodes store different data; replica sets are usually referred to as such, and not as a cluster. You can upgrade a single server to a shard within a sharded cluster without restarting `mongod`, but if you want replication you need to start with `--replSet` (though you don't need to actually configure the replica set).

Comment: "Generally/typically" aside, a cluster is, as the wiki definition says, a group of loosely coupled physical machines, and that's what I was referring to. Following and propagating incorrect terminology will cause more confusion than it solves, even it comes from 10gen's documentation pages ;)